# What is the better Regex Expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

In my program, I convert an invoice pdf to text. I am looking for a better Regex Expression to parse the string. The results of my conversion are a very long string:

> This is a very long string. Invoice Total: $1,399.52 Continuation of very long string.

I want to parse out the 1399.52 Following the "Invoice Total:".

Here is my first attempt:

```
    Dim text As String = "This is a very long string. Invoice Total: $1,399.52 Continuation of very long string."
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("Invoice Total:\s*\$((\d|\.)*)")
    Dim m As Match = re.Match(text)
    For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)

        If(groupIdx = 1) Then
            txtTotal.Text =  m.Groups(groupIdx).Value
        End If
    Next


Matches Found:
[0][0] = Invoice Total: $1,399.52
[0][1] = 1399.52
[0][2] = 0
```

The code works, but I know there is a better way.

Comment: This looks overcomplicated. Try something like https://ideone.com/FmXPDC, `"Invoice Total:\s*\$(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)"`  regex and `m.Groups(1).Value.Replace(",","")` to get the value.

Comment: Also I think this pattern `Invoice Total:\s*\$((\d|\.)*)` will not match `Total: $1,399.52` right?

Comment: Why not `Invoice Total: \$([\d,.]+)` ? Or even `Invoice Total: \$(\S+)`. If you know you have no space between `$` and the end of the number.

Comment: `Dim decValue As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(Regex.Match[Input], "\$[\d,.]+\S").Value, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```vb
Dim text As String = "This is a very long string. Invoice Total: $1,399.52 Continuation of very long string."
Dim re As Regex = New Regex("Invoice Total:\s*\$(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)")
Dim m As Match = re.Match(text)
If m.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value.Replace(",",""))
End If
```

See the [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/FmXPDC) and the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Invoice%20Total%3A%5Cs*%5C%24%28%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B%29*%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%29&i=This%20is%20a%20very%20long%20string.%20Invoice%20Total%3A%20%241%2C399.52%20Continuation%20of%20very%20long%20string.).

**NOTE**: The regex can be simplified depending on the real life context. If the number ends with the first whitespace, you can use a mere

```
Invoice Total:\s*\$(\S+)
```

where `\S+` will match one or more non-whitespace chars.
*Regex detail*:

- `Invoice Total:`  - a literal string (used as left-hand side context)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:,\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a comma and one or more digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional occurrence of a period  and one or more digits.

Note that the commas can be removed with a mere `.Replace(",","")`, or you may cast the extract number to a `decimal` [as shown by Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992561/what-is-the-better-regex-expression#comment118418405_66992561). Note you cannot extract the number without commas into Group 1 because regex parses the string continuously from left to right, and cannot skip chars when writing the (sub)match value into a group.